# Bind XAML elements to entities TwoWay

Tags: wpf, data-binding, two-way-binding

I want to bind an entity property (say `Salary`) to a property of a `XAML` element (like a `TextBox.Text`) 
and use this binding to save `Text` of `TextBox` to salary field which is bound as a entity property to 'Text' of some `TextBox`.

Something like the following :

```
<Grid DataContext="Employee">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Salary, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just can bind Properties in xaml  - so your salary have to be a property and not a field. if your Employee is the class with the salary you can set datacontext to an instance of it. you can do it in xaml or codebehind or with binding.

```
public class Employee //implement INotifyPropertyChanged to get the power of binding :)
{
    public decimal Salary {get;set}
}
```

view.xaml

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:Employee/>
  </Grid.DataContext>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Salary, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
 </Grid>
```

you can set the datacontext in many ways

Answer (score 2):

### XAML Two-Way Binding, 'Windows Universal' style, step-by-step

In Visual Studio 2017, create a Visual C# blank app (Universal Windows). Name it 'MyProject'.

Add a class `Employee` to it, and then modify boilerplate code as follows:

```
// Employee.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string salary;
        public string Salary
        {
            get
            {
                return this.salary;
            }
            set
            {

                if (value != this.salary)
                {
                    this.salary = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method MUST BE called by the Set accessor of each property for TwoWay binding to work.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        // Constructor with one parameter
        public Employee(string annualSalary) { salary = annualSalary; }
    }
}
```

Notice that class `Employee` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface.

Add class `EmployeeViewModel` to project, and modify boilerplate code as follows:

```
// EmployeeViewModel.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        private Employee defaultEmployee = new Employee("50000");

        public Employee DefaultEmployee { get { return this.defaultEmployee; } }

    }
}
```

Modify `MainPage.xaml.cs` boilerplate code as follows

```
//MainPage.xaml.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace MyProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel();


        }
        public EmployeeViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Modify `MainPage.xaml` boilerplate code as follows:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--TextBlock will provide visual feedback that the two-way binding is working-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="Control" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.DefaultEmployee.Salary, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <!--TextBox has two-way binding-->
        <TextBox x:Name="Input" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.DefaultEmployee.Salary, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <!--Button does nothing other than allow TextBox to lose focus-->
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Hello" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
          Foreground="Green"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Notice, both `'Input'` TextBox and `'Control'` TextBlock are bound to the same `Salary` property of `DefaultEmployee`. The idea is that you edit and change the salary in the `'Input'` TextBox, and then you can visually see the Two-Way binding at work, because the `'Control'` TextBlock will update. This happens when the `'Input'` TextBox loses focus (it is to allow the change of focus, for instance after pressing TAB key, that the `'Hello'` button was added - the button in itself does absolutely nothing).

Build and Run. Modify salary, and either TAB or click button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No you cant  do like that. You cant Set the Class name to the DataContext. It should be the instance of Employee class.